# Refreshing a part of of a page when a button is clicked on-screen

Tags: python, html, flask, htmx

I'm quite new to Flask and HTML, and I've been working on a project I had in mind for years and just now getting to know the tech to execute it. Trying to build an random image generator (from a db of images) that will prompt 4 images upon loading the site, and give the user the ability to refresh the images without reloading the page. I also need to add the ability to check a checkbox to filter the images that can be loaded.

I would love to understand what I'm doing wrong, and also to learn best-practice methods if you spot something I'm doing wrong.

I have a working base for the site, but I've been trying to go over HTMx to solve my problem but I've only had partial success. While I do manage to load new images, it doesn't replace the old ones, but loads a new set entirely and adds it to the screen but to where the button is located.

routes.py:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, request 
from app.methods import image_picker

at/app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(): 
if request.method in ['GET', 'POST']: 
    images = image_picker() 
    return render_template('index.html', 
            image1=images.image1path, image1name = images.image1name, 
            image2=images.image2path, image2name = images.image2name, 
            image3=images.image3path, image3name = images.image3name, 
            image4=images.image4path, image4name = images.image4name, 
            safety=safety)
```

and index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.3"></script>

<body>
    <table width="50%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="25%"/>
            <col width="25%"/>
            <col width="25%"/>
            <col width="25%"/>
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><b><u>Header1</u></b></td>
            <td align="center"><b><u>Header2</u></b></td>
            <td align="center"><b><u>Header3</u></b></td>
            <td align="center"><b><u>Header4</u></b></td>
        </tr>
        <div id="generate_content">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">{{ picture_1_title }}</td>
                <td align="center">{{ picture_2_title}}</td>
                <td align="center">{{ picture_3_title}}</td>
                <td align="center">{{ picture_4_title}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><img src="{{ picture_1 }}" height="64" width="64"/></td>
                <td align="center"><img src="{{ picture_2 }}" height="77" width="120"/></td>
                <td align="center"><img src="{{ picture_3 }}" height="77" width="120"/></td>
                <td align="center"><img src="{{ picture_4}}" height="77" width="120"/></td>
            </tr>
        </div>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="dlc_check">Include animal pictures?
                </form>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <button type="button" hx-post="/" hx-swap="outerHTML"> Click here to generate!</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <br>
    </table>
</body>        
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not using the `hx-target` attribute. By default it is set to `this`. Thus, every content you receive as a response from the server will replace your `<button type="button" hx-post="/" hx-swap="outerHTML"> Click here to generate!</button>`.

What I suggest is, you place a little `<div id="target"></div>` somewhere in your html and use the `hx-target` attibute:

```
<button type="button" 
        hx-post="/" 
        hx-swap="outerHTML"
        hx-target="#target">
    Click here to generate!
</button>
```

Comment: Okay so I tried naming my table and calling `hx-target="#tableName"`. This creates a table inside my table, so I was wondering if I can create the structure of the page separately from the content of it, and give all the content a section id so I can refresh the content alone?

Comment: I remember some time ago that htmx did not mix so well with tables. So what you would do is have a `page.html` and in this page you have a `<div id="xxx" hx-target="this" hx-swap="innerHTML"></div>` and inside this `div` there is the a `part.html` that only consists of the table... now you can just switch that table on button click. I am not a flask expert, but you can see the `htmx` part in Adamchainz's Django-htmx-example: https://github.com/adamchainz/django-htmx/tree/main/example/example/templates (check how the HTML files include each other).